# convert year and month as date format in hive

Tags: sql, date, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I have year and month format as below. Year and Month are column names

```
Year  Month
2020  January
2019  October
```

and want to transform them so that they are in the following format

```
01-01-2020
01-10-2019
```

I have tried working with

```
cast(concat('01-',substring(month,1,3),'-',year) as timestamp) as Date_col
```

but couldn't make it work. Help is very much appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can achieve this by using `DATEPART` and `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT CONCAT('01-', FORMAT(DATEPART(MM, [Month] + ' 01 ' + [Year]), '0#'), '-', [Year]) AS Date_col
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast `01-Jan-2019` to timestamp, but even if it worked, timestamp in Hive is not in format required: `dd-MM-yyyy`. timestamp has this format: `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'` (nanoseconds are optional).

`unix_timestamp` function converts given format string to unix timestamp in seconds, `from_unix_time` converts unix timestamp to given format.

Use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat('01-',month,'-',year),'dd-MMM-yyyy'),'dd-MM-yyyy')` to convert from `'dd-MMM-yyyy'` to `'dd-MM-yyyy'`

Demo:

```
with 
your_data as (
select stack(2, 
2020, 'January',
2019, 'October'
        ) as ( Year, Month)
)
select Year, Month, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat('01-',month,'-',year),'dd-MMM-yyyy'),'dd-MM-yyyy')  as Date_col
from your_data
;
```

Result:

```
year    month     date_col
2020    January   01-01-2020
2019    October   01-10-2019
```

Also this will work (without concat with `01-`, using 'MMM-yyyy' format):

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(month,'-',year),'MMM-yyyy'),'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

If you want to convert to true Timestamp, do the same without specifying output format:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(month,'-',year),'MMM-yyyy')) --returns 2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

Use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class docs as a format reference

Comment: still getting Date_col as null. year and month columns are string date type

Comment: @sadashiva My example if copy-pasted also does not work?

Comment: this worked for me... from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat('01-', substring(month,1,3), '-', year), 'dd-MMM-yy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')

Comment: @sadashiva You have 2 digits year? In the question it is 4 digits. I think the difference in this. MMM works for full month like January